# Grunt expand files, what patterns are acceptable in src?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

Snippet from gruntfile.js

```
sass: {
    compile: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'css/',
            src: ['^[^_].scss'],
            dest: '../css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

This should work [according to rubular.](http://rubular.com/r/qxwmGV4KdZ)

Basically I want to compile all .scss files in the 'css' directory, unless they start with an underscore. However, that pattern doesn't match anything?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this pattern: `['*.scss', '!_*.scss']`. It'll make the distinction more explicit, too.

```
sass: {
    compile: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'css/',
            src: ['*.scss', '!_*.scss'],
            dest: '../css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

If you want to match recursively (files in subfolders of `cwd`), use `**/*`

```
sass: {
    compile: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'css/',
            src: ['**/*.scss', '!**/_*.scss'],
            dest: '../css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

Learn more about [**Grunt Globbing Patterns**](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), *which aren't the same as regular expressions*.

Comment: thanks it helped me, though I think RegExp would have been a better fit for them to use.