# Assemble: How to control output extension

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

My question is about [Assemble](http://assemble.io) 0.4

I have an input file with the name "main.js.md.hbs"
I need to get "main.js.html" as output name.
How to do this?
I have a Grunt task like this:

    `assemble: {
      options: {
        assets: '<%= config.dest %>/assets',
        flatten: true,
        layoutdir: 'templates/layouts',
        layout: 'base.hbs',
        data: 'data/metadata/*.{json,yml}',
        partials: 'templates/partials/*.hbs'
      },
      docs: {
        options: {
          layout: 'markdown_doc.hbs'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'content',
            src: ['**/*.hbs'],
            dest: 'dist/',
            ext: '.html'
          }]
      }
  }`

With the provided config Assemble generates "main.html" (cuts off ".js" part).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your files specification.  In src, you are globbing all .hbs files, then you specify the extension as .html for all.  One solution that covers the main.js.md.hbs example would be to use two different file specifications with different extensions to separate out the *.js.md.hbs -> *.js.html case:

```js
assemble: { 
    options: { 
        assets: '<%= config.dest %>/assets', 
        flatten: true, 
        layoutdir: 'templates/layouts', 
        layout: 'base.hbs', 
        data: 'data/metadata/*.{json,yml}', 
        partials: 'templates/partials/*.hbs' 
    }, 
    docs: { 
        options: { 
            layout: 'markdown_doc.hbs' 
        }, 
        files: [
            { 
                expand: true, 
                cwd: 'content', 
                src: ['**/*.js.md.hbs'], 
                dest: 'dist/', 
                ext: '.js.html'
            },
            { 
                expand: true, 
                cwd: 'content', 
                src: ['**/*.hbs', '!*.js.md.hbs'], 
                dest: 'dist/', 
                ext: '.html' 
            }
        ] 
    } 
}
```

I'm sure this is not the elegant long-term solution, but I don't know exactly what glob patterns you need.  I found the following related question helpful, which also pointed out the documentation for [Grunt File Globbing Patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

[Grunt expand files, what patterns are acceptable in src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286848/grunt-expand-files-what-patterns-are-acceptable-in-src)